# Use AWS git server on Sourcetree

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree

I have build myself a git server using Amazon Web Services (AWS). And I am able to checkout the repository under terminal with following command with no problem.

```
git init && git remote add origin git@ec2-12-345-678-910:my-project.git
```

However, if I try it with SourceTree, I keep having the warning"This is not a valid path/URL warning". Anybody know what's wrong?

[image]

I am pretty much stuck. I will appreciated it if you have any comments.

---

By the way, I also tried putting `git@...` in `Source Path / URL` without `ssh://`.

Comment: You only need to add the part starting with `git@ec2-...`. The rest of the commands are needed to create a local git repo and add the remote. Sourcetree does this for you

Comment: I made a mistake when taking the screen shot. I will modify it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Did you solve that by the way?

Comment: Nope, i figure that bit bucket is a better choice. You can give it a try. It is private as well. I have been using it ever since them.

Answer (score 1):

Try ,as said, without the ssh:// and in the end modify to :~/path/to/folder/my-project.git

example:

```
ubuntu@ec2-213-23-32.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:~/path/to/folder/my-project/.git
```

Don't forget to add your EC2 identity, otherwise you will get the “Permission denied (publickey).” error. Run on terminal:

```
ssh-add path/to/privateEC2key.pem
```

Now you will be able to clone your project from your amazon machine. :)